# Manipulate a stacked dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

I would like to transform a stacked dataframe to a regular dataframe in pandas.
The raw df is：

| Score | Amy | Brian | Carl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| test2 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

after stacking：

|  |  | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | Amy | 5 |
|  | Brian | 6 |
|  | Carl | 7 |
| test2 | Amy | 3 |
|  | Brian | 2 |
|  | Carl | 4 |

The result I want is as follows:

|  | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | Amy | 5 |
| test1 | Brian | 6 |
| test1 | Carl | 7 |
| test2 | Amy | 3 |
| test2 | Brian | 2 |
| test2 | Carl | 4 |

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: `df.melt('Score', var_name='name', value_name='score')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a little longer than @Quang Hoang's answer above but it should also. It picks up after the stacking the DataFrame

```
test1   Amy     5
test1   Brian   6
test1   Carl    7
test2   Amy     3
test2   Brian   2
test2   Carl    4

# Reset index to flatten DataFrame
result = df_stk.reset_index().copy()

    level_0 level_1 0
0   test1   Amy     5
1   test1   Brian   6
2   test1   Carl    7
3   test2   Amy     3
4   test2   Brian   2
5   test2   Carl    4

# Rename columns
result.rename(columns={'level_1':'name',
                       0: 'score'},inplace=True)

    level_0 name    score
0   test1   Amy     5
1   test1   Brian   6
2   test1   Carl    7
3   test2   Amy     3
4   test2   Brian   2
5   test2   Carl    4

# Set test values to index of DataFrame
result.index = result['level_0']

level_0 level_0 name    score
test1   test1   Amy     5
test1   test1   Brian   6
test1   test1   Carl    7
test2   test2   Amy     3
test2   test2   Brian   2
test2   test2   Carl    4

# Rename index to blank
result.index.name=''

       level_0  name    score
test1   test1   Amy     5
test1   test1   Brian   6
test1   test1   Carl    7
test2   test2   Amy     3
test2   test2   Brian   2
test2   test2   Carl    4

# Drop test column from DataFrame
result.drop(columns=['level_0'],inplace=True)

        name    score
test1   Amy     5
test1   Brian   6
test1   Carl    7
test2   Amy     3
test2   Brian   2
test2   Carl    4
```